# Function to view a Binary Tree / Binary Search Tree in an actual Tree format?

Tags: python, printing, tree, binary-search-tree

Is there a way to view a BT/BST in such a manner:

```
               5
             /   \
            2     7
           / \   / \
          1   3 6   8
```

I've browsed the internet an came across a method which displays the Tree, but it is tilted to the left as such:

```
                 8
            7
                 6
       5
                 3
            2
                 1
```

I want a function which will print the BT/BST in the first manner.

**Edit:**
for a tree with height 4

```
           05
        /       \
      03         06          
    /   \       /   \       
  03    04    09    12    
  / \   / \   / \   / \      
 01 02 06 05 07 08 10 11
```

Comment: can we assume nodes have a single digit? it matters for correct spacing of the output.

Comment: max 3 would be preferable , so an integer 1 would likely be represented as 001, if that helps.

Comment: You can use level order traversal and then print it using how you print `pascals tree`.

Comment: ummm, have you considered what a 4-level tree will look like? because there are going to be large gaps between the upper nodes as the depth increases.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi might have to give that a try, but if it has already been done then I would really appreciate it if you could link the source here.

Comment: @DariushMazlumi no not really but if it does the job then it does the job.

Comment: @Amaan would be great if you could provide an example of your desired output for a tree of depth 4. as details matter in how the main loop has to be written.

Comment: ^^ this. The example in the question is too small. Please provide example output for a complete tree with 2 more levels, so having 31 nodes.

Comment: @DariushMazlumi, I've edited my question and added a tree with height/depth 4 and how the Tree should be displayed if only 2 digits  keys are allowed in the tree.

Comment: That's a tree with height 3, not 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide below a program that will generate an output like this:

```
          100
   ┌───────┴───────┐
  12              230
┌──┴──┐         ┌──┴───┐
8    32        205    323
└─┐   └─┐    ┌──┴──┐   └─┐
 10    43   201   213   999
      ┌─┘          └─┐
     39             225
    ┌─┘
   38
  ┌─┘
 37
```

You can run it out of the box. It takes numbers as input and adds them to a BST, and prints the result, and then asks for the next input:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = self.right = None

class BST:
    PADDING = 3 # Space between horizontally adjacent node labels
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.root = None
        for value in values:
            self.insert(value)

    def insert(self, value):
        def insert(root, value):
            if not root:
                return Node(value)
            if value < root.value:
                root.left = insert(root.left, value)
            else:
                root.right = insert(root.right, value)
            return root

        self.root = insert(self.root, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        def indent(lines, margin):
            if margin >= 0:
                return margin
            spaces = " " * -margin
            lines[:] = [spaces + line for line in lines]
            return 0

        def merge(left, right):
            if not left or not right:
                return left or right
            offsetright = max(len(leftline) + BST.PADDING - (len(rightline) - len(rightline.lstrip())) 
                for leftline, rightline in zip(left, right)
            )
            indent(right, -indent(left, offsetright))
            return [
                leftline + rightline[len(leftline):]
                for leftline, rightline in zip(left, right)
            ] + left[len(right):] + right[len(left):]

        def buildlines(node):
            if not node:
                return []
            lines = merge(buildlines(node.left), buildlines(node.right))
            label = str(node.value)
            half = len(label) >> 1
            if not lines:
                return [" "*half + "*", label]
            i = lines[0].index("*")
            if not node.right:
                lines[0] = " "*i + "┌─┘"
                i += 2
            elif not node.left:
                i = indent(lines, i - 2)
                lines[0] = " "*i + "└─┐"
            else:
                dist = len(lines[0]) - 1 - i
                lines[0] = f"{' '*i}┌{'─'*((dist >> 1) - 1)}┴{'─'*((dist - 1) >> 1)}┐"
                i += dist >> 1
            j = indent(lines, i - half)
            return [" "*(i + max(0, half - i)) + "*", " "*j + label] + lines
            
        return "\n".join(buildlines(self.root)[1:])


tree = BST()
while True:
    val = int(input("insert value: "))
    tree.insert(val)
    print(tree)
```

Comment: Thank you @trincot for the above code, it's way better than the one which I enquired for. Thanks alot.